# Increment operator's behavior

Tags: c

Why does

```
int a, b = 10;
b = b++;
printf ("%d", b);
```

output 10

while

```
int a, b = 10;
a = b++;
printf ("%d", b);
```

outputs 11

how does this work? Why doesn't 'b' increment in first case?

Comment: hint: what does `b =` do?

Comment: other hint: you aren't officially allowed to change b twice in the same instruction. Different compilers might compile it differently.

Comment: Another hint `b = ++b;` do?

Comment: See [Why can't we mix increment operators like i++ with other operators?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278384)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b++ performs assignment with not-incremented value while ++b would do assignment with the incremented value. You only need b++; in your code without assignment to increment. As someone also pointed out b = b++; and b = ++b; are not good segments of code and you are at the mercy of the compiler.